# Regular expressions combined with list for numbers written as words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract information about people wounded from several articles. The issue is that there are different ways in which conveying that information in journalistic language since it can be written in numbers or in words.

For instance:

```
`Security forces had *wounded two* gunmen inside the museum but that two or three accomplices might still be at large.`

`The suicide bomber has wounded *four men* last night.`

`*Dozens* were wounded in a terrorist attack.`
```

I noticed as most of the times numbers that goes from 1-10 are written in words rather than in numbers. And I was wondering how to extract them without incurring in any convoluted code and just list regular expression with words from 1-10.

Shall I use a list? And how it would be included?

This is the pattern I used so far for extracting the number of people wounded with digit:

```
text_open = open("News")
text_read = text_open.read()
pattern= ("wounded (\d+)|(\d+) were wounded|(\d+) injured|(\d+) people were wounded|wounding (\d+)|wounding at least (\d+)")
result = re.findall(pattern,text_read)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import re

regex = r"(\w)+\s(?=were)|(?<=wounded|injured)\s[\w]{3,}"

test_str = ("`Security forces had wounded two gunmen inside the museum but that two or three accomplices might still be at large.`\n\n"
    "`The suicide bomber has wounded four men last night.`\n\n"
    "`Dozens were wounded in a terrorist attack.")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for match in matches:    
    print (match.group().strip())
```

Output:

```
two
four
Dozens
```

`\w+\s(?=were)` : `?=` look ahead for `were` , found capture word using `\w`

`|` or

`(?<=wounded|injured)\s\w{3,}` : `?<=` look behind , capture word if wounded or injured occurred before word and `{3,}` mean length of word is 3 or more , simply to avoid capturing word i.e. `in` and every numeric word has min length 3 so it's fine to use it.